making an installation program for electron.js solution
I successfully made an electron.js solution and zipped up the file to hand over the work to the computer where it would be used.  It is launched by typing : "npm start" from a command line after the code is unzipped into a folder.  It has been a while since I set this up, but I remember that I think the process insisted I download the latest version of NPM.  My question is this.  How can I create a true installer for an electron.js solution?  Can I bundle the NPM with this installation process?
